# Table Cells Are A Big

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm going to make this as clear as possible. In my Xcode project, I am reusing a prototype cell and I want each cell to open a different view controller. How would you guys think I would be able to do that?

Here is a pic of the reusable cell in my Main.storyboard:

[image: This is the pic of the reusable cell]

Here is the result of the cells being reused:

[image: This is the link to pic 2]

And here is the code of my controller class:

```
import UIKit

class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var extraButton:UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 242.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        if revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

            revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 150
            extraButton.target = revealViewController()
            extraButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))

            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "watchkit-intro")
            cell.postTitleLabel.text = "WatchKit Introduction: Building a Simple Guess Game"
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "custom-segue-featured-1024")
            cell.postTitleLabel.text = "Building a Chat App in Swift Using Multipeer Connectivity Framework"
        } else {
            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "webkit-featured")
            cell.postTitleLabel.text = "A Beginner’s Guide to Animated Custom Segues in iOS 8"
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

To be clear, I want each cell in pic 2 to open a different view controller. For example, I would want Cell 1 to open New View Controller 1, Cell 2 to open New View Controller 2, and Cell 3 to open New View Controller 3.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: _"Table Cells Are A Big"_ what does it mean?

Comment: I guess a question I have is why do you want each cell to open a different view controller?  Is it something like, you have x different types of view controllers and some cells will trigger one type while others will trigger other types?  Or are you planning to have every cell in your tableview open a different view controller?  Which prompts me to ask again: why?

Comment: @WERUreo Yeah! you guessing right. He wanted to open different VC on click on every different cell. but i'm not getting, if there are 50 cells in his `UITableView` then he need 50 VC's and thats was not a good practice.

Comment: @appmaker Reuse your codes and VC's. Mention in your question why you need different VC's for different Cell click because it is not a good practise. There can be any good approach anyone of us can tell you, but first mention your final result.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I only want three cells in my UITableViewController and I just recently released an update on an error I encountered. Please check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @WERUero I am only planning to have 3 cells in your tableview open a different view controller. Also I have released an update on an error I encountered. Please check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should implement tableview's delegate method

e.g.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
            // open VC1
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        // open VC2
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2
    {
        // open VC3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it something like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
      // segue to view 1
    case 1:
      // segue to view 2
    case 2:
      // segue to view 3
    case 3:
      // segue to view 4
    default:
      // default go here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement `tableView(_:, didSelectRowAt:)`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let newViewController1 = ...
        present(newViewController1, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let newViewController2 = ...
        present(newViewController2, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        let newViewController3 = ...
        present(newViewController3, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a gesture recognizer to your table view cells and implement a custom cell delegate. It doesn't seem like that would be necessary in your situation though, so I won't recommend it. It seems like it may be overkill. If you're interested, though:

```
class NewsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: NewsTableViewCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let recognizer = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    func tapped() {
        delegate?.cellTapped(self)
    }
}

protocol NewsTableViewCellDelegate {
    func cellTapped(_ cell: NewsTableViewCell)
}

extension MyViewController: NewsTableViewCellDelegate {
    func cellTapped(_ cell: NewsTableViewCell) {
        if cell == cell1 { }
        else if cell == cell2 { }
        else if cell == cell3 { }

        //You would have to manually determine how to check if a cell is cell1, cell2, or cell3, since you wouldn't have an indexPath available.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For both the error,

1. Remove segue from `main.storyboard` because you are using segue from `storyboard` but in code work you presenting your `ViewConroller`.
2. In code work, replace your lines by below

**

```
`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main.Storyboard", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"myViewController") as! UIViewController
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)`
```

**

If you are pushing your VC, then use this below code:

```
let myViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewController") as! Conversation_VC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Xcode is telling me that your code doesn't work and I have removed the segues. Xcode is telling me that it Expected declaration

Comment: @appmaker give me your Gmail iD, I will mail you demo regarding to this.

Comment: my email address is gregjohnson88888@gmail.com

Comment: my email address is gregjohnson88888@gmail.com